# Projecting unto principle component subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the derivative of an inner product in some real hilbert space?

Trying to show the following: Given $H$ (real hilbert space), $f \in H$, and$V=span{\{f_1,...,f_n\}}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
proj_v(f) = \langle f, f_1 \rangle_H f_1 + ... + \langle f, f_n \rangle_H f_n 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I was thinking to start off like: 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\min\limits_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \|f-\boldsymbol{\alpha}^T\boldsymbol{f}\| \\ = \min\limits_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \langle f-\boldsymbol{\alpha}^T \boldsymbol{f}, f-\boldsymbol{\alpha}^T \boldsymbol{f}\rangle_H
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Inner product defined: 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mbox{for some} f,g \in H \\
f = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ik(y_i, x)\\
b = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_ik_i(y_i, x) \\
\langle f, g\rangle_H = \boldsymbol{\alpha^T[K(i,j)]_{i,j}\beta}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

With basis of $V$ being principle component vectors of the $\{K(y_i,x)\}_{i=\{0..n\}}$  i.e. (specteral decomp of $\boldsymbol{K(y,x)}$ gram matrix)

Comment: Do you want to calculate the Frechet derivative of the function $f:H \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) =\langle x, h\rangle$ for a given $h\in H$?

Comment: I edited the question. Please take a look